# How to enter a value in a cell based on row-column combination in an Excel .xlsx file using C#?

Tags: c#, excel

I just want to set a cell value using row and column header names
i.e. if I have an excel (with hierarchy in Excel screenshot), I want to add "val" in row3,col3  (without using A4,D4)
how can I do this in C# ?

[Excel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kwjz6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround :)

```
Public static void WriteExcel(string excelFilepath,string sheetName, string rowHeader, string columnHeader, string requiredText)
    {
        var excelPath = excelFilepath;
        var excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        //excelApp.Visible = true;

        Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(excelPath);
        Excel.Worksheet xlSheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[sheetName]; // get first sheet
        Excel.Range xlRange = xlSheet.UsedRange; // get the entire used range
        try
        {
            //Getting location of row and column headers location
            var rowRange = xlRange.Find(rowHeader, LookAt: Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole);
            var columnRange = xlRange.Find(columnHeader, LookAt: Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole);

            //Getting Row Header X and Y values
            var rowRangeX = rowRange.Column;
            var rowRangeY = rowRange.Row;

            //Getting Column ow Header X and Y values
            var columnRangeX = columnRange.Column;
            var columnRangeY = columnRange.Row;

            //Setting required cell with string value
            xlSheet.Cells[rowRangeY, columnRangeX].Value = requiredText;
        }
        finally
        {
            //Saving the file and closing it                
            excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Save();
            excelApp.Workbooks.Close();
            excelApp.Quit();
        }         
    }        
}
```